# SQL COUNT conditional on the results another table

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I'm having hard time with this scenario.

Table 1 contains information when a player was on a team.

```
Table1

playerID   | yearID
----------------------
Player1    | 2000
Player1    | 2001
Player2    | 2000
```

Table 2 contains ballot information with the Hall of Fame. A player can be on multiple times.

```
playerID | BallotYear | Inducted
---------------------------------
Player1  |   2010     |    N
Player1  |   2011     |    N
Player2  |   2010     |    Y
```

I am trying to count how many times a player shows up on Table1 conditional on them never being inducted based on Table2.

```
Desired Result

playerID  |  Count on Table 1
---------------------------
Player1   |        2
```

The issue I have come across is that Player1 returns 4, instead of 2. I have looked into a number of different functions, but I keep getting the same results. This is what I have come up with.

```
select Table1.playerID, count(Table1.playerID)
from Table1
join Table2 on Table1.playerID = Table2.playerID
where Table2.inducted = 'N'
group by Table1.playerID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter out players that have ever had a `'Y'` in the `inducted` field.  If so:

```
select t1.playerId, count(*)
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.playerID = t1.playerID and t2.inducted = 'Y'
                 )
group by t1.playerId;
```

Comment: should it be (select t2.playerID ...) or (select 1 ..) is correct?

Comment: This got me much closer. The numbers are correct, but the inducted players still show up.

Comment: @MaineBYU try with change i suggested in my comment above

Comment: @MaineBYU KD is correct, replace the `(select 1 ...` with `(select t2.PlayerID ...`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Left join which will also add to performance of query

```
select t1.playerId, count(*)
from table1 t1 left join
(select distinct playerID
                          from table2 
                          where inducted = 'Y'
                         ) t2 on t1.playerID = t2.playerID
where t2.playerId is null
group by t1.playerId
```

Comment: That is considerably faster. Thank you KD.

Comment: Glad it helped. i always try to avoid sub queries as it may harm performance if amount of data is significant.